# Udacity parallel programming, unspecified launch failure

Tags: cuda

I'm trying to complete homework #3 for Udacity course parallel programming. I have ran into the following CUDA error:

```
CUDA error at: student_func.cu:150  
unspecified launch failure cudaGetLastError()
```

The error is encountered when I launch a kernel that is meant to reduce an array.

Here is my cuda code (everything is fine with `copy_f`):

```
__global__
void copy_f(const float* const d_src,
            float* const d_dst,
            size_t length) {
  size_t pos = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  if (pos >= length) {
    return;
  }
  d_dst[pos] = d_src[pos];
}

__global__
void reduce_min(float* const d_buf,
                float* global_min_value,
                size_t length) {
  size_t pos = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

  while (length > 1) {
    size_t mid = (length + 1) >> 1;
    if (pos >= 2 * mid) {
      return;
    }
    if (pos >= mid) {
      float min_value = 1.f;
      if (pos < length) {
        min_value = d_buf[pos];
      }
      if (d_buf[pos - mid] > min_value) {
        d_buf[pos - mid] = min_value;
      }
    }
    __syncthreads();
    length = mid;
  }
  if (pos == 0) {
    *global_min_value = d_buf[0];
  }
}
```

And function which is using it:

```
float *d_buf_f;
unsigned int *d_hist, *d_buf_ui;

void your_histogram_and_prefixsum(const float* const d_logLuminance,
                                  unsigned int* const d_cdf,
                                  float &min_logLum,
                                  float &max_logLum,
                                  const size_t numRows,
                                  const size_t numCols,
                                  const size_t numBins)
{
  // Step 0: Setting kernels and allocating memory
  const size_t length = numRows * numCols;
  const size_t blockCols = 512;
  const size_t gridCols = (length + blockCols - 1) / blockCols;
  const dim3 blockSize(blockCols, 1, 1);
  const dim3 gridSize(gridCols, 1, 1);

  checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(&d_buf_f, sizeof(float) * length));
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(&d_hist, sizeof(unsigned int) * numBins));
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(&d_buf_ui, sizeof(unsigned int) * numBins));

  // Step 1: Min and max
  copy_f<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(d_logLuminance, d_buf_f, length);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize(); checkCudaErrors(cudaGetLastError());
  reduce_min<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(d_buf_f, &min_logLum, length);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize(); checkCudaErrors(cudaGetLastError());

  // Step 5: Releasing memory
  checkCudaErrors(cudaFree(d_buf_f));
  checkCudaErrors(cudaFree(d_hist));
  checkCudaErrors(cudaFree(d_buf_ui));

  cudaDeviceSynchronize(); checkCudaErrors(cudaGetLastError());
}
```

Comment: you are passing a host variable to your reduction kernel.

Comment: @talonmies, why do you think so? I'm passing `d_buf_f` to `reduce_min` and as you can see, `d_buf_f` was allocated via `cudaMalloc`.

Comment: &min_logLum is a host address

Comment: @talonmies, thanks, now I got it! What is the best way of getting round it?
I can allocate some memory for this, but it looks little bit ugly.

Comment: your kernel also won't work correctly even after you fix that.

Comment: @talonmies, what's wrong now?

Comment: The entire idea of the kernel is wrong. there is no such thing as global synchronisation. If you have more than one block, this can never work

Comment: I got it, thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the problem is this:

```
reduce_min<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(d_buf_f, &min_logLum, length);
```

`&min_logLum` is a bare host address which is illegal to use within the kernel. This will need to be replaced by a valid address in device memory.

After you fix this, you should find that your kernel only works correctly if you run a single block. There are design issues with the kernel which need to be fixed. There is a very good discussion about the design of reduction kernels in this [white paper](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf) from NVIDIA. I recommend reading it.